# How can I prevent videos from playing when someone clicks on an overlay?

Tags: mobile-safari, jqmobi

I have tried the recommended -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d on my video elements to prevent videos from starting when the user clicks on an overlay that is above the video element, but the videos still play :s

Seems to be an issue with mobile safari as there is NO problem in Chrome.

Can anyone provide any other recommendations?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you capturing the event on the overlay?  If so, call event.stopPropagation and that should block it from bubbling up to the video element.